# Drawing a cuboid with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to draw a cuboid with css (like this http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Cuboid.png but ONLY 3 visible faces needed)

Lots of stuff checked, but nothing found exactly :S

Can anyone help?

SOLVED. The code is:

```
<style>
#cubetop {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background: green;
    -webkit-transform:    
        translateX(20px)
        skew(-45deg, 0deg);
}

#cubeface {
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    background: yellow;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

#cuberight {
    width: 40px;
    height: 60px;
    background: navy;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    -webkit-transform:    
        translateY(-20px)
        skew(0deg, -45deg);
}
</style>
<div id="cubetop"></div>
<div id="cubeface"></div>
<div id="cuberight"></div>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with css3, you can use transforms. Have 3 separate div elements and apply the transformations on each.

Something like this in Mozilla

```
-moz-transform:    rotate(15deg)
                   translateX(230px)
                   scale(1.5);
```

And Like this in IE

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.4488887394336025, M12=-0.388228567653781, M21=0.388228567653781, M22=1.4488887394336025, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
```

Alternatively try :

http://www.useragentman.com/tests/cssSandpaper/cube3.html